# Moving files from a plugin into folders using an XML file

Tags: xml, file, joomla, move

I am creating a plugin for an online store. This plugin is supposed to implement the files inside into folders already created of this online store. I would like to know how could this be done from the XML install file that is used in my example for Joomla.

Could anybody please shed me some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: If  I understand right what do you want to do is to install the plugin  with the component. Is it?

Comment: The plugin contains files which should be installed in an existing component. For example a file which should go to the file of "Models", another in "Controllers" and a folder inside "Views".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the link below. It contains details how to create the XML.

http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Components:xml_installfile

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

XML may differ depending on the Joomla version you are using. Please search on Google get the particular XML.

Install the component with the new files. It will update the existing files as you need.